# Выдаёт ошибку отсутствия Microsoft Visual C++ при установке модуля на PyPy

Tags: python, pip, pypy

Хочу установить модуль [cexprtk](https://pypi.org/project/cexprtk/0.1.0/) на PyPy. В основном пользуюсь CPython, PyPy хочу попробовать использовать для запуска только одного проекта. Прописываю команду

```
pypy -m pip install cexprtk
```

и выдаётся ошибка:

```
Collecting cexprtk
  Using cached cexprtk-0.4.0.tar.gz (440 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: cexprtk
  Building wheel for cexprtk (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  ├Ч python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  тФВ exit code: 1
  тХ░тФА> [14 lines of output]
      C:\Users\User\Desktop\project\pypy\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py:771: UserWarning: 
Usage of dash-separated 'description-file' will not be supported in future versions. Please use the underscore name 'de
scription_file' instead
        warnings.warn(
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-pypy39
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-pypy39\cexprtk
      copying cython\cexprtk\_exceptions.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-pypy39\cexprtk
      copying cython\cexprtk\_functionargs.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-pypy39\cexprtk
      copying cython\cexprtk\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-pypy39\cexprtk
      running build_ext
      building 'cexprtk._cexprtk' extension
      error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visuals
tudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for cexprtk
  Running setup.py clean for cexprtk
Failed to build cexprtk
Installing collected packages: cexprtk
  Running setup.py install for cexprtk ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  ├Ч Running setup.py install for cexprtk did not run successfully.
  тФВ exit code: 1
  тХ░тФА> [16 lines of output]
      C:\Users\User\Desktop\project\pypy\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py:771: UserWarning: 
Usage of dash-separated 'description-file' will not be supported in future versions. Please use the underscore name 'de
scription_file' instead
        warnings.warn(
      running install
      C:\Users\User\Desktop\project\pypy\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py:34: Set
uptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
        warnings.warn(
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-pypy39
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-pypy39\cexprtk
      copying cython\cexprtk\_exceptions.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-pypy39\cexprtk
      copying cython\cexprtk\_functionargs.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-pypy39\cexprtk
      copying cython\cexprtk\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-pypy39\cexprtk
      running build_ext
      building 'cexprtk._cexprtk' extension
      error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visuals
tudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
      [end of output]

error: legacy-install-failure

├Ч Encountered error while trying to install package.
тХ░тФА> cexprtk

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for output from the failure.
```

Microsoft Visual C++ установлен, и не только тот который нужен, там много версий.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На CPython всё установилось без проблем.

Comment: У вас Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 установлена? или более поздняя? Или вы не понимаете о чём я?

Comment: @Александр Ну, если исходить из версии (самый правый столбец на скриншоте), то установлена.

Comment: Но может не установлена система сборки именно 14.0

Comment: build tools c++ 2015 нужен, а может криво установили.

Comment: И вообще то что на скрине это не то от слова вообще не то.

Comment: Вы вот это подсказкой воспользовались? """Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visuals
tudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/"""

Comment: @Александр Ну конечно же! Я поэтому и задаю вопрос про Micrososft Visual, и то что он у меня вроде установлен. Счаc попробую установить build tools 2015.

Comment: Установил 2015, теперь говорит windows.h: No such file or directory

Comment: Слушай друг ты не чего не установил нормально, раз у тебя такие ошибки. Посмотри гайд по установке.

Comment: windows.h это стандартный заголовочный файл, и если его нет то всё криво сделано.

Comment: К чему ты вот это кричишь <<Ну конечно же!>>? Я же говорю что у тебя не чего не установлено как бы ты меня не убеждал в обратном. Потому что это давно всё "схавано и какано". А если хочешь помощи то действуй по инструкции которые тебе предлагают. А не трать моё время на споры с тобой.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Проблема решена.**

Пошаговое руководства для тех, у кого возникла такая же проблема при установке данной (или другой) библиотеки на PyPy. **Эта инструкция точно будет работать на Windows 10.**
Оказывается требовался данный компонент :)

- Установить на компьютер [Visual Studio Installer](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/).
  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
- После установки у вас должно появится это окно.
  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
- В появившемся окне жмём на эту галочку (никакие компоненты больше не требуются).
  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В правом нижнем углу нажмите кнопку **Установка при скачивании**!
Всё.